# Ajax.BeginForm response contains previous values even if I pass another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a simple action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult New(Feedback feedback)
    {
        feedback.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (TryValidateModel(feedback))
        {
            FeedbackRepository.Add(feedback);
            var model = new Feedback
                            {                                   
                                SuccessfullyPosted = true
                            };

            return PartialView(MVC.Shared.Views._FeedBackForm, model);
        }

        return PartialView(MVC.Shared.Views._FeedBackForm, feedback);
    }
```

So, idea is if received data is validating fine, return partial view with empty feedback entity. 
Thing is, that if i look at firebug response, I see old values coming back, how weird is this?

Form looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Feedback.New(), new AjaxOptions
                                                                 {
                                                                     UpdateTargetId = "contactsForm",
                                                                     HttpMethod = "post"
                                                                 }))
{           
    
        

            
    
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)
    
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)
    
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
    
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Phone)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Phone)                       
    
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Comments)

        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comments, new { cols = 60, rows = 10 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Comments)
    
    if (Model.SuccessfullyPosted)
    {
    
        Feedback sent successfully.
    }
    
        
}
```

Is it possible somehow to disable this behavior and how `PartialView(MVC.Shared.Views._FeedBackForm, model)` manages to get different model?

update: I see stackoverflow ate all html from by view and can't find how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ModelState` is primary supplier of model values. Even if you pass your model to `View` or `PartialView`, `EdiorFor` will first look into `ModelState` for corresponding property value, and if it does not exist there, only then into model itself. ModelState is populated when posting to controller (old feedback). Even if you create new feedback and pass it as model, `ModelState` already contains values from previously posted feedback, so you get old values on client. Clearing modelstate before successfull post result will help you.

```
FeedbackRepository.Add(feedback);
var model = new Feedback
                {                                   
                   SuccessfullyPosted = true
                 };
ModelState.Clear(); // force to use new model values
return PartialView(MVC.Shared.Views._FeedBackForm, model);
```

---

*See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942366/mvc-3-value-lost-after-sent-to-client/6942579#6942579) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269478/default-values-for-model-fields-in-asp-net-mvc3/7269762#7269762) links for examples of related situations*